# How do i make my bot detect if a user sends an embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

*I'm struggling to make a **selfbot detection system** with my bot.*
*i want to make it so the bot checks if a normal user sends an embed and if it does it kicks them*

> this is my code so far

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  embed = message.embeds
```

Comment: So what problem did you run into while coding it? Or are you just asking for someone else to code your things?

Comment: @FierySpectre im asking for guidance

Comment: Well you already have a variable that contains the embeds from that message, so check if the person is not a bot & if the list of embeds is not empty

Comment: can a user even send an embed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple thing to do, I advise you learn more about python and programming in general before you continue.

That being said, you can just check the length of message.embeds by doing `len(message.embeds)` and doing a check to see if its greater than zero.